# Why i am getting authentication error in MATLAB while i try to use HTTP

Tags: matlab, http

I am trying to query SiriDB via Matlab. I am getting the positive response from my log-in attemps. However when i try to query, i get the error: "not authenticated".

Please see my code below:

```
clear;clc
import matlab.net.http.*
import matlab.net.http.field.*
import matlab.net.URI 
import matlab.net.http.Credentials

strct1 = jsondecode('{"username": "my_user_name", "password": "my_password"}');
strct2 = jsondecode('{"query": "select last() from ''example_query''"}');
uri = 'http://example_adress/auth/login';

request = RequestMessage( 'POST',ContentTypeField( 'application/json'),strct1);
complete(request,uri);
response = send(request,uri);
complete(response);
response.Body.string

uri = 'http://example_api';

request = RequestMessage( 'POST',ContentTypeField( 'application/json'),strct2 ); 
complete(request,uri)
response = request.send( 'http://example_api' );
complete(response);
response.Body.string
```